# database connection not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?
$test1 = mysql_connect("localhost","username","pass");
if (!$test1)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("database", $test1);
$letter = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
$letter1 = substr($letter,6);
$query = "SELECT * FROM letter WHERE username='" . $letter1 . "'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url('<? echo $row["backpic"]; ?>');
    background-attachment:fixed;
    margin-bottom:36px;
    }
</style>
```

That is my code for retrieving a field from the mysql database and setting that field as a background image (the field contains a url).

For some reason this code doesn't work. I have checked all the values and they are supposed to be correct because this exact same code exists in another file and it works perfectly there.

Please help!

---

There is no error generated.

By the way, there is line of code that comes before all this: include("connectval.php");

There that file has the same code as this but different variable names and the substring part is not there. I don't think that interferes with this code though.

Comment: what is the error that was generated from the script?

Comment: It always dumbfounds me when we're told "it doesn't work", but no error message/code/description is provided to explain what is *actually wrong*. It doesn't work; ok. What is happening? Do you get an error?

Comment: there is no error generated. I even tried printing out the field that is supposed to fetched from the database and it doesn't print it out while if i do something like echo "hello"; it prints hello so for some reason $row['backpic']; doesn't have any value.

Comment: Then you need to look at the query, `"SELECT * FROM letter WHERE username='" . $letter1 . "'"`, in plaintext. If it looks ok, try it in your phpMyAdmin Run SQL tab and see what it says. If you get no results, I suspect you may be doing a search based on a wildcard, so it could be you need `"SELECT * FROM letter WHERE username LIKE '" . $letter1 . "%'"` to find usernames which start with a certain letter or whatnot. But that's just a guess.

Comment: I personally use MySQLi instead of MySQL driver and I intent to start using PDO. Take a look here [link](http://goo.gl/RgxmO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this code works in a different file but not this one, it's likely a path problem - are the URLs in the database fully qualified or relative?

What does the generated HTML look like? What **exactly** is in the database?

Steps I'd follow to debug this:

(I assume by "it doesn't work" you mean you don't see a background image? If so, you should be explicit!)

- Work backwards - The browser isn't showing the image. Why?
- The browser uses the image URL to load the image - is it correct in the source of the page?
- If the URL is correct, copy/paste it into the address bar - does the image load?
- If it's not correct, look at what's in the database and work out what you need to do to correct it.

My guess is that urls in the database are in the form: `/Images/Image.jpg` which works fine when the PHP is alongside the `Images` folder but wrong when loaded from a different folder - try making them fully qualified (`http://www.example.com/Images/Image.jpg`). If you can't change the database, add the `http://www.example.com` yourself in code.

**EDIT:**

As suggested in comments on OP by Jared Farrish:

Try printing out `$query`. Copy/paste the string into [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) or [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) - Do you see the correct results?

Comment: The database contains user values like email, name, profile pic. $row['backpic']; is supposed to have the profile pic value loaded into it which is a url to an image. Everything else works as coded in the file. There is only one part of this file that uses this code which is when trying to put on the background pic so everything else works right.

Comment: You still aren't answering the question : what does the URL look like? unless you can answer that, I can't help you. is it [Absolute or relative](http://www.compugoddess.com/relvsabs.htm)? What does the CSS block look like if you right-click on the page and view source? Edit your question with the answers

Comment: Does the page show ANYTHING at all? or is it just blank. If it's blank, you may have PHP errors turned off in the server config - check the server logs and php.ini settings.

Comment: The OP I believe is saying the field is not printing anything out.

Comment: @JaredFarrish possibly - it's very hard to tell but if so, the OP should still be able to answer re: db contents (although it would be irrelevant). There's nothing in OPs code that should fail silently - So either there's an error, error reporting is turned off or the code is behaving in an unexpected but valid way. The last is hard to pin down without any detailed debugging info...

Comment: I did get it to work. It turns out that some variables were deleted mistakenly which created problems. Anyways, thanks to all of you for trying to help me. I wouldn't have realized this if I didn't go through the code like you guys told me to. Thanks!

Comment: @user1079641 glad we could help. Please either post your solution as an answer and accept it, delete the question [if it's unlikely to be of use to others], or accept the answer that helped the most. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to output the variable `$a951168545`, which does not exist.

You've loaded the results of your database query as an array into `$row`, so you need to output an index of `$row`. What you should probably be echoing out in the background-image part is `$row['backpic']`.

If all else fails, insert the line `var_dump($row)` which will show you exactly what is being loaded into your `$row` variable, and should indicate what you need to do to display the value you are looking for.

Comment: I messed up at the code while copying and pasting it here and so I did have $row['backpic']; but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

What is **`<? echo $row["backpic"]; ?>`** outputting?

Try this:

```
<?php
    // You can enable the report of all PHP errors using ONE of the 3 lines below
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    //error_reporting(E_ALL);
    //error_reporting(-1);


$myhost = "localhost";
$myuser = "myuser";
$mypwd = "mypassword";
$mydb = "mydatabase";
$mysqli = new mysqli($localhost, $myuser, $mypwd, $mydb);

if ($mysqli->error) {
    printf("Connection failed: %s\n", $mysqli->error());
    exit();
}

$letter = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
$letter1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string(substr($letter,6));
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM letter WHERE username = %d", $username);
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

// $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM); //$row[0]
// $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); //$row['field']
// $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH); //$row['field'], $row['0']
// $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); //$row['field']
$row = $result->fetch_object(); //$row->['field']

/*if($row > 0) :
    printf ("<h2>%s (%s)</h2>", $row[0], $row['backpic']);
endif;*/

$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url('<?= $row->backpic; ?>');
    background-attachment:fixed;
    margin-bottom:36px;
    }
</style>
```